# How to hold the values static on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make the values of a text box and labels static on the page when user goes from attendance page to another page I have set the `enableviewstate="true"` but still its not holding the data when I go to another page it vanishes.

Here is my html code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="auto-style3">Login Time:</td>
    <td class="auto-style4">
        <asp:Label ID="lblLogin" enableviewstate="true" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td class="auto-style5">Logout Time:</td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblLogout" enableviewstate="true" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="auto-style3">Remarks:</td>
    <td class="auto-style4">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxRemarks" runat="server" enableviewstate="true" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my c-sharp code:

```
TimeSpan logintime = System.DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.Parse("09:20:00.000");
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    { 
        lblAttendance.Text = Session["user"].ToString().Split('^')[1];
        lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
}

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btnLogin.Text == "Login(Daily Attendance)")
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["REGDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Track_UserLog", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", Session["user"].ToString().Split('^')[0]);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        lblLogin.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");
        btnLogin.Text = "Logout(Daily Attendance)";
        if (logintime > time)//&& TextBoxRemarks.Text.ToString() == String.Empty)
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["REGDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand("update tblAttendanceDetails set Remarks=@rem where LoginDate=convert(date,GETDATE()) AND EmployeeId=' " + Session["User"].ToString().Split('^')[0] + " '", cn);
            cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rem", TextBoxRemarks.Text);
            cd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
    else if (btnLogin.Text == "Logout(Daily Attendance)")
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["REGDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Track_logout", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", Session["user"].ToString().Split('^')[0]);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        lblLogout.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");
        btnLogin.Text = "Login(Daily Attendance)";
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you read the session object, but where do you set it?

Comment: @PatrickHofman i have set it on the login page...

Comment: It is unclear to me where exactly it is going wrong. Can you explain more what actually happens and what the steps are to reproduce?

Comment: Which form is not maintaining values? Can you mark your code for what does what?

Comment: @PatrickHofman actually i have created an employee attendance system and i have a login page(here i am creating the session) from which when employee logins get on to the home page then he marks his attendance on the attendance page after clicking "Login(Daily attendance)" button and if he is late he put some remark and next time when he comes back i want that login time and remark values static on that page but when i go on the another page after marking the attendance the values are no longer available....

Answer (score 0):

Viewstate works for only same page postbacks.

From MSDN:

> View state provides state information for a specific ASP.NET page. If you need to use information on more than one page, or if you need the information to persist across visits to the Web site, you must use another method for maintaining state. You can use application state, session state, or profile properties.

If you want to see same data when you get request that page you should store data in application state, session state, or profile properties.

Then you should manually bind this data to pages elements.

Comment: It seems your answer isn't helpful since OP doesn't seem to be using view state at all. He uses the Session object to store the variables.

Comment: He mentioned that he used enableviewstate = true but data is vanishing when he goes to another page at the first paragraph. I think op expects to data will remain when he comes to viewstated page from another page.